# ban a word in a string

Tags: php, validation, email

I have a simple email form I have edited for my needs and all is working well.....
except....

the form has words already present in the text fields, so the user knows what to type..

these words are

Name
Address
Postcode
Phone
Message

if a user tries to send a "blank email"....the form regects it because of the email check and the phone check (email requires @ + . and phone requires numbers and spaces only!)

what I am trying to do is ban the words "Name" "Address" "postcode" and "phone".....

message does not matter to me!

here is the script I am Using:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "me@me.com";
$email_subject = "My Email";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['address1']) ||
    !isset($_POST['postcode']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['message'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you    submitted.');      
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email = $_POST['email']; // required
$address1 = $_POST['address1']; // required
$postcode = $_POST['postcode']; // required
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
$message = $_POST['message']; // not required

$error_message = "";

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$address_exp = "/^[A-Za-z 0-9 .',-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($address_exp,$address1)) {
$error_message .= 'The Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$postcode_exp = "/^[A-Za-z 0-9 .',-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($postcode_exp,$postcode)) {
$error_message .= 'The Postcode you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$phone_exp = "/^[0-9 ]+$/";
if(!preg_match($phone_exp,$phone)) {
$error_message .= 'The Phone number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "address1: ".clean_string($address1)."\n";
$email_message .= "postcode: ".clean_string($postcode)."\n";
$email_message .= "phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$whofrom=$_POST["email"];
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

hope you can help me out as I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: Why? Why ban those words specifically? You're not accomplishing anything worth-while by doing so. If they can't enter "name" as a bogus name, they'll just enter "naem" or "bob" or literally *any other string of garbage*.

Comment: What about using input element [*placeholders*](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder)? They're native in HTML5 and many modern browsers support them and they can be shim'd in older browsers; and they don't submit *anything* to the server.

Comment: Also, your email regular expression is broken, and will reject many completely valid email addresses. Try `"/^.+@.+\..+$/"`.

Comment: It sounds like the inputs have default values where upon submitting they aren't technically blank, but you don't want to receive just those default placeholders. Banning those words is the wrong solution to the problem, I think.

Comment: You're also going to be really bother anybody named Adèle or anybody who lives on Rue Galilée.

Comment: all valid points but justin is correct the default values are Name,Email,Phone,Etc..... as for adjusting the code I was pleased to get it sending mail, I am now trying to make it better! thanks for the help so far

Comment: thanks for the heads up meagar!...i have changed that email string on your suggestion! Lee

Comment: You're also going to be really bother anybody named Adèle or anybody who lives on Rue Galilée. – meagar....how do I get around that one? Lee

Answer (score 3):

Do an array check on all the words with the word you are testing it with.

Example:

```
$bad=array("Name", "Address", "Postcode", "Phone Message");

foreach ($_POST as $post) {
    if (in_array($post,$bad)) {
        died("Used a reserved word!");
    }
}
```

Comment: In his code there's a function called `died($error_message)`.

Comment: I recommend checking the words in lowercase to avoid problems.

Comment: Sorry 
Dave.......would you mind explaining where I put this code?

Comment: If you want to check all the post contents, you can do a `foreach` on `$_POST`, I'd recommend checking the values that you need to check though, example: `name`,`address`, etc. Oh and check my edit, you should put this code right after you check if it is set.

Comment: @Dave Good call, I didn't catch that.